# Download button auto clear by any input change

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have two `input selection` and an `action button` to generate a plot and download the data. I would like to clear the output contents (plot and download button) any time there is a change in the input selection. The code below will only clear the plot and not the download button. Not sure if the `reactiveValues`under the `downloadhandler`is correct.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)


ui = fluidPage(
  textInput("textT", label = "Title", value = ""),
  textInput("textX", label = "X-Axis Label", value = ""),
  actionButton("Btn", "Run", icon=icon("play-circle")),
  plotOutput('plot1'),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Btn>0", downloadButton("dwload", "Download"))
  )

server = function(input, output, session) {    

  v <- reactiveValues(clearAll = TRUE)

  observeEvent(c(input$textT, input$textX), {
    v$clearAll <- TRUE
  }, priority = 10)

  observeEvent(input$Btn, {

    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      if (v$clearAll) 
        return()
      else
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(x= gear, y= carb)) + geom_line() +ggtitle(input$textT) + xlab(input$textX)
    })

    output$dwload <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste0("Checks-", gsub(" ", "_", gsub(":", ".", Sys.time())), ".xlsx")
        },
      content = function(file) {
        if (v$clearAll) 
          return()
        else
          quick_xlsx(mtcars, file=file)
      }
    )

    v$clearAll <- FALSE

  }, priority = 10)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain a bit the context ? That would help. Why do you want to remove the plot and the button ? Should they be definitely removed, or can they come back ?

Comment: Thank you Stephane for your question. The idea is to clear all outputs (including the download button) so that the user won't see any output while changing the inputs --this is a simple case of a more complex shiny app with several inputs-- However all the inputs are controlled via the 'Run' button in a observeEvent. So the outputs are cleared anytime there is a change in the input and displayed back anytime the user click the 'Run' button. This works so far with the 'plot' but not with the 'download button'. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `renderUI` and `req`:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)


ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("textT", label = "Title", value = ""),
  textInput("textX", label = "X-Axis Label", value = ""),
  actionButton("Btn", "Run", icon=icon("play-circle")),
  uiOutput("widgets")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {    

  hideAll <- reactiveVal(TRUE)

  observeEvent(list(input$textT, input$textX), {
    hideAll(TRUE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$Btn, {
    req(input$textT)
    req(input$textX)
    hideAll(FALSE)
  })


  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x= gear, y= carb)) + geom_line() + 
      ggtitle(input$textT) + xlab(input$textX)
  })

  output$dwload <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("Checks-", gsub(" ", "_", gsub(":", ".", Sys.time())), ".xlsx")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      quick_xlsx(mtcars, file=file)
    }
  )

  output$widgets <- renderUI({
    req(!hideAll())
    tagList(
      plotOutput('plot1'),
      downloadButton("dwload", "Download")
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you Stephane. This solved it. However, cliking on `Run` will display the output without inputing. Then we can still use `req()` for `input$textT` and `input$textT`. Please edit the code  and add `req(input$textT)`  and `req(input$textX)` in `observeEvent` for `input$Btn` and I will accept the answer. Thank you once more